# pscp alias for current host

Tags: windows, putty

Is there any way to send files via pscp using `-load profile` without specifying host if I have already specified it in profile?

I want to specify only source path, destination path and profile without specifying user and host, because It's already in profile.

Example: I want to create script in batch that will send to root of host from profile given as first argument files given at second argument:

```
@echo off
pscp.exe -load %* SOMETHING:/
pause
```

But I don't know what to put instead of `SOMETHING`. I need that script to create send to menu entries in Windows 8.1 (on that windows shortcuts in send to menu can't take %1, %2, %* etc, so I must create script to rearrange order of parameters in pscp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly:

1. you're working on a windows host, locally connected as "winuser" account;
2. on such host, you can succesfully use "putty" to SSH-access a remote host (let's call it "remote_host") authenticating as the remote "root" user. Let's suppose you're authentication is "password-based";
3. you have a putty profile for "remote_host", that includes not only the remote hostname/ip_address, but also the "root" remote username;
4. you need a BAT file by which you can "pscp" something to/from your local machine from/to "remote_host", without explicitely reporting the "root" username in such a BAT file. This, 'cause in the putty profile you already have specified it.

Is this right?

If yes, a BAT file like this:

```
@echo off
pscp c:/tce-test.tce imac:/tmp
pause
```

will copy the local windows c:\tcp-test.tce file to the remote host specified within the putty "imac" profile, connecting to such host with the username specified in the same "imac" putty profile, and writing the file to the remote /tmp folder.

In other words, as clearly stated in the [pscp documentation](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter5.html#pscp-usage-basics-host)

```
5.2.1.2 host
The name of the remote server, or the name of an existing PuTTY saved session. In the 
latter case, the session's settings for hostname, port number, cipher type and username 
will be used.
```

you can use, in place of the host parameter, the name of a saved putty session. Exactly what you need.

Having said all the above, let me add following considerations:

- with such an approach, you're enforcing a **fixed remote user**: the one specified in the putty profile. This is a constraint you may not like;
- by not specifying a username in the putty profile, pscp will fallback in using the username you're using in your local windows host ("winuser", in the example above): if local usernames have similar usernames defined on the SSH-server, this could be a plus;
- a safe and comfortable way to avoid typing the SSH-password, is to rely on SSH-key authentication. With windows, you can find the [Pageant](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter9.html) agent that can be launched on windows startup and take control over the (local) user authentication keys. Once the agent is running and controlling the keys, all the putty-family-softwares (putty, pscp, etc.), as well as lots of other sofwares, might properly ssh-authenticate without prompting the user for any password at all (please don't see this as security weakness, as it's exactly the opposite: with keys, you're *strenghtening* your authentication schemas);
- if you rely on keys for authentication, you can point PSCP to proper key file, by using the "-i" option

From: [Official PuTTY documentation](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-identity):

```
3.8.3.18 -i: specify an SSH private key
The -i option allows you to specify the name of a private key file in *.PPK
format which PuTTY will use to authenticate with the server. This option is only 
meaningful if you are using SSH.
For general information on public-key authentication, see chapter 8.
This option is equivalent to the ‘Private key file for authentication’ box in the Auth 
panel of the PuTTY configuration box (see section 4.20.7).
```